# JENKINS: Is it possible to Stop\Abort other running\pending jobs by running a specific job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've got a job that need to stop other running\pending jobs when its being run.

Is it possible to do automatically?

Comment: You could execute a shell command which in turn will cancel a certain item like this `curl --data '' 'http://example.com:8080/queue/cancelItem?id=<ID>'`. I also think you can use the `Groovy` plugin and write a small script to cancel specific builds: `jobName = Thread.currentThread().executable.toString().split()[0];
for (item in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getQueue().getItems()) {
  if (jobName.equals(item.task.getName())) {
    println("Aborting current build due to a more recent build request.");
    hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().interrupt();
    break;
  }
}`

Comment: You can stop running or queued build via Rest API like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21022672/1586762)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I just spent a bunch of time looking for an answer, hopefully this will save someone time:

Use the jenkins http api to stop a build:
  wget http://your.jenkins.host/job/JOBNAME/lastBuild/stop

If you are using matrix permissions, make sure your Anonymous user has Read and Cancel permission on Jobs.

Answer (score -2):

There is a plugin available to kill another job.

You can use this plugin :

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Signal+killer

This plugin extends ProcessKiller extension point and sends signal (currentlly SIGKILL) to given job via native GNU C library call.