# Jenkins REST API to stop build using token

Tags: api, rest, jenkins, build, jenkins-api

How to stop a build from Unix CLI using Jenkins REST API without specifying username/password credentials on command line, but using a build token?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.

From @JesseGlick's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021905/how-to-stop-a-build-in-jenkins-via-the-rest-api#comment-41230229):

> And `token` is only available for `build` (and `buildWithParameters` and `poll`). It cannot be used on any other REST APIs. In general you should use BASIC authentication with API tokens.

---

The answer from [How to stop a build in Jenkins via the REST api ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021905/how-to-stop-a-build-in-jenkins-via-the-rest-api) claims you could stop/cancel a build with a token, but you'll find that the tokenized request (and no credentials) will redirect you to a login URL.