# Jenkins-How to achieve the two jobs are mutual dependency

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

Jenkins CI is a very powerful tool, some plugins can be installed using it.
Lately I have had a demand about two parallel processing jobs.
We know that a lot of plugins have achieved this functionality, such as join plugin, Trigger parameterized plugin and so on.
However I need another functionality as well.

The new functionality we want is the following:
Job A and Job B are processing parallel, if job A build fails, then Job B stops running instantly.

I haven't found any plugin achieving that.

Can you help me and inform me if there is any plugin with such functionality?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Post Build task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) plugin on your Job A and Job B.

You can set it to run when the jobs are failed: `Log Text -> BUILD FAILED`

And when the build is failed you can execute a `Script` to stop the job you want to be stopped using the jenkins API as it is being discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021905/how-to-stop-a-build-in-jenkins-via-the-rest-api).

```
http://<Jenkins_URL>/job/<Job_Name>/<Build_Number>/stop
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer helped you solve your issue, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Use DSL Script with Build Flow plugin.

```
     JOB A
       |------> JOB B
       |------> JOB C 
                  |------> JOB D
```

try this Example for your execution:

build("job A")

parallel
   (
      {build("job B")}
      {build("job C")}
   )

build("job D")

- If you'd like to stop the mess with downstream / upstream jobs chains definitions. Or when you want to add a full hierarchy of Jenkins jobs that will be executed in sequence or in parallel. Add context to your buildflow implementing parameter inheritance from the MultiJob to all its Phases and Jobs. Phases are sequential while jobs inside each Phase are parallel.
  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin
- My Favorite try this Try the Locks and Latches plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locks+and+Latches+plugin

Comment: These plugins are usefully and powerfully, I only need part of the function, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipeline parallel keyword.

```
stage('parallel job'){
        parallel{
            stage('job1'){
                steps{ build 'job-1'}
            }
            stage('job2'){
                steps{ build 'job-2'}
            }
        }
    }
```

Job-1 and Job-2 runs in parallel.
If job-1 fails while job-2 is running, then job2 is aborted.

It goes to next stage, only if all parallel stages are done in success.