# Kill Jenkins job and all its children immediately

Tags: linux, jenkins

I am trying to find a way to kill a Jenkins job and all its children immediately. Is there a such a way to do this in Jenkins?

Initially I was looking at finding a process group and killing it:

```
kill -TERM -- -....
```

But `ps` is not returning anything Jenkins related.

1) Is there a way to kill a job and **its children** in Jenkins and

2) If yes, is it possible to create a job that can take another job as a parameter to kill it?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [stopping a build in Jenkins via the REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021905/how-to-stop-a-build-in-jenkins-via-the-rest-api)

```
http://<Jenkins_URL>/job/<Job_Name>/<Build_Number>/stop
```

That should stop the right process, and its children.

Comment: Thanks, will this stop, let's say, Jenkins job that runs a script that has *psql* query in it? Will the query be killed?

Comment: @AntonKim Yes: all children process should be stopped.

Comment: How is it different from stopping manually in Jenkins itself?

Comment: @AntonKim it is the equivalent, but without accessing the web GUI: remote call, which can be part of a script.

Comment: It's not been killed either through UI or through kill command
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645161/pg-dump-not-been-killed-inside-script-with-kill-command

Comment: @AntonKim Maybe the process has been orphaned.