# pg_dump not been killed inside script with kill command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, command-line

Question 1:

Jenkins job has a script running, inside the script there is `pg_dump` command.

I'd like to kill this job and all children processes but

```
kill -9 PID
kill -TERM PID
```

is only killing Jenkins job and not killing `pg_dump`

Question 2:

How can I identify the Jenkins job through command line? Right now:

`ps -ef | grep jenkins` will return

`jenkins  28706  2608  0 17:39 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -xe /var/lib/jenkins/tmp/jenkins5167617865881040149.sh`

I just know that this is the job because it's the only one running, but obviously the name in Jenkins itself is different.