# How to stop an zombie job on Jenkins

Tags: curl, jenkins

I have a situation where I have 2 jobs.
My main 1st jenkins project trigger an another 2nd project using "Trigger/call builds on other projects" plug-in.
My 2nd project is kind of server which I am starting first using trigger and my main 1st project process all over it.
Now I want to stop my 2nd zombie project once my 1st project build is done.

I have found some reference like below:-

[How to stop an unstoppable zombie job on Jenkins without restarting the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456592/how-to-stop-an-unstoppable-zombie-job-on-jenkins-without-restarting-the-server)

But I want to stop my zombie job automatically once my main project build complete

I have found one way

[How to stop a build in Jenkins via the REST api ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021905/how-to-stop-a-build-in-jenkins-via-the-rest-api)

I have tried by hitting Rest API of Jenkins

http://localhost:8086/job/JOB_Name/14/stop

But getting error like below

> ```
> >     HTTP ERROR 403
> >     
> >     Problem accessing /job/TestZAP/14/stop. Reason:
> >     
> >         No valid crumb was included in the request
> ```

[image]

I have also hit curl command as below :-

```
C:\Users\Shubham Jain>curl -X POST http://admin:252ec0f4ac@localhost:8086/job/TestZAP/build -H "CRUMB"
```

But getting error as below:

> Error 403 No valid crumb
>   was included in the request
>
> ### HTTP ERROR
>   403
>
> Problem accessing /job/TestZAP/build. Reason:
>
> ```
>     No
> valid crumb was included in the request
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Powered by Jetty://
>   9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
>
> ---

Is there is any way to do this?

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

At the end I have disabled CSRF Protection -> Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits
After hitting URL like :-
http://localhost:8086/job/TestZAP/15/stop

Still getting response are appears as :-

> POST required POST is required
>   for hudson.model.AbstractBuild.doStop

Comment: This related question has a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456592/how-to-stop-an-unstoppable-zombie-job-on-jenkins-without-restarting-the-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just disable the disabled CSRF Protection -> Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits from Jenkins